# How to align radio group in fieldset

Tags: alignment, radio-group, fieldset

I have a form with a radio group in a fieldset. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/fea67gtv/34/). I have two issues.

1 - The legend Options has a space on the left which I can't figure out how to remove. It should left-align with the Path word above it.

2 - The radio buttons start one line down from the legend. I want the first radio button to be on the same line as the word Options.

Would someone explain how to fix this, please? Here is my code:

```
    <style>
    .form-title {display:inline-block;margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold;width:100px;border:1px solid red}
    .form-data {display:inline-block;margin-left:10px;border:1px solid blue}
    .form-radio {display:inline-block;margin-left:102px;}
    .form-legend {display:inline-block;margin-left:0px;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;margin:0;padding:0;}
    </style>

    <form name="settings-form" method="post">   
       <div>
         <div class="">
           <label for="domain" class="form-title">Domain</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-data" name="domain" id="domain">
         </div>  
         <div class="">
           <label for="path" class="form-title">Path</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-data" name="path" id="path">
         </div>  
         <div> 
           <fieldset style="border:0;">
             <div class="form-legend"><legend>Options</legend>
               <div class="form-radio">      
                 <label for="dcc0"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt0" id="dcc0">Check 1</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc1"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt1" id="dcc1">Check 2</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc2"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt2" id="dcc2">Check 3</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc3"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt3" id="dcc3">Check 4</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc4"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt4" id="dcc4">Check 5</label><br>
               </div>
             </div>   
           </fieldset>
         </div>
       </div>   
       <div style="margin-top:130px;"> 
       <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="save-settings" id="save-settings" value="Save Settings">
       </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to move the first option by itself and removed the fieldset as can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/fea67gtv/37/)

```
    <style>
    .form-group {margin-bottom:8px;}
    .form-title {display:inline-block;margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold;width:140px;}
    .form-data {display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid green;}
    .form-legend {display:inline-block;margin-left:5px;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;border:0;}
    .form-radio {display:inline-block;margin-left:172px;border:0;}
    .form-radio-title {display:inline-block;margin-left:8px;margin-right:98px;border:0;font-weight:bold;}        
    </style>

    <form name="settings-form" method="post">   
       <div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="domain" class="form-title">Domain</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-data" name="domain" id="domain">
         </div>  
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="path" class="form-title">Path</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-data" name="path" id="path">
         </div>  
         <div> 
         <div class="">
           <label for="dcc0" class="form-radio-title">Options</label>
           <input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt0" id="dcc0">Check 1
         </div>  
         <div class="form-radio">      
         
               <div class="form-radio">      
                 <label for="dcc1"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt1" id="dcc1">Check 2</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc2"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt2" id="dcc2">Check 3</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc3"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt3" id="dcc3">Check 4</label><br>
                 <label for="dcc4"><input type="radio" class="form-data" name="opt4" id="dcc4">Check 5</label><br>
               </div>
             </div>   
         </div>
       </div>   
       <div style="margin-top:130px;"> 
       <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="save-settings" id="save-settings" value="Save Settings">
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is this an answer that solves the problem? If so, please explain. If not, it should be an edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry. I thought my statement was obvious. It solve the problem by moving the first item in the radio group to its own line instead of being part of the fieldset as in my first post.